# Add space between bars of different groups in errorbarh of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, errorbar

I have a plot in which for different groups I have a horizontal bar with different color using errorbarh of ggplot. However, they are all layed on top of each other without any space. I would like to put a little space between bars so I can compare and contrast. A piece of the plot is depicted below:
[image: errorbarhGroups]

my code is as below as well:

```
ggplot(allData, aes(x=score, y=path, xmin = min, xmax = max, group=group, col=group, fill=group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(-1,1), colour="#FA8072", linetype = "longdash") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(0), colour="grey", linetype = "solid") +
  geom_errorbarh(height=.1) + theme_bw() +
  xlim(-2.5, 2.5)
```

Comment: Have you tried `position = "dodge"`?

Comment: @AllanCameron As your recommendation I modified the errorbarh line as geom_errorbarh(height=.1, position = "dodge") + theme_bw() +
  xlim(-2.5, 2.5) , but it doesnt have any effect.

Comment: that would work if your y axis was a factor. Presumably it's numeric (you didn't include any data, so we can only guess here)

Comment: @AllanCameron I just modified the uploaded photo in my original post. Yes for each path, each group has different score showing by different colors. I hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me - position_dodge should work since your y axis is a factor/character variable. Could you please post the data so that we can test and verify solutions? The output of `dput(allData)` added to your question would get you a solution quickly. Without it, I don't think we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I found how I can do this. Using position the spaces between bars can be changed. So the modified code is as follows:

```
ggplot(allData, aes(x=score, y=path, group=group, col=group, fill=group)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.7)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(-1,1), colour="#FA8072", linetype = "longdash") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(0), colour="grey", linetype = "solid") +
  geom_errorbarh(height=.1, aes(xmin = min, xmax = max), position = position_dodge(0.7)) + theme_bw() +
  xlim(-2.5, 2.5)
```